# How can I stack a usable button over the scrim on a modal bottom sheet in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to stack a button on top of the overlay of a bottomModalSheet, however I'm finding that the button doesn't get triggered, and instead triggers the dismiss function.

Here's some code (p.s. the code seems to clip the button in the flutter dart pad so try in your IDE instead).

You'll notice that when you click the lower half of 'Click 2', the event triggers, but when you click the upper half, the dismiss triggers.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: [
                Container(height: 200),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 190,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Click 2'),
                    onPressed: () { print('Ok'); },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
      child: Text('Click'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is no possible to do with showModalBottomSheet since the clickable area has to be inside the stack

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20798#issuecomment-611478841

My solution was to build a custom modal sheet using

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
      PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: false, // for modal transparency
        pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Material(color: Colors.black38, child: Stack(...)),
      ),
    );
```